# image slider for drupal

Tags: 7, media, javascript

I'm making my first drupal website and I want to have a image slider on the homepage. I would like there to be a page in the backend where the end-user can upload and choose which images are in the slideshow. I looked at the [nivo-slider](http://drupal.org/project/nivo_slider) module but it only allows the creation of one slider and what I really need are two separate sliders one for English and one for French content.

Is there a module that has this functionality already? If I wanted to create something like this myself would that involve making a module or can it be part of my theme's code somehow?

Comment: Use the power of Drupal luke! You want the slider to be a 'content type', then you can create as many as you want. You should probably use 'field_slideshow' module for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the 
[View Slideshow module](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) and create many blocks of slider from the content you create.

> Views Slideshow can be used to create a slideshow of any content (not just images) that can appear in a View. Powered by jQuery, it is heavily customizable: you may choose slideshow settings for each View you create.

Comment: if you land up with views_slideshow module, might be [this](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow_xtra) module can also be helpful.

Comment: I was able to get this module working.. do I have to create separate slideshows for each language or is there a way I can have one slider that picks the language based on the users language? I set up a slider_image content type that is translatable. When I view my translated slider image on its own I can toggle between the translations but when it is in the slideshow it shows both translated images back to back

Comment: Power of views - you can have one slider, and make views only pick up nodes with language == current site language.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of other sliders for this.

Dynamic display block

Featured Content Slider

jCarousel and more

Answer (score 0):

Going to make this even easier for you...

Use field_slideshow module...

http://drupal.org/project/field_slideshow

and follow the easy setup here...

http://zugec.com/74-create-slideshow-using-field-slideshow-module

Answer (score 0):

If you like the Nivo Slider, use [Views Nivo Slider](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_nivo_slider) to create multiple Nivo Sliders. While it shows that it only has a development version for drupal 7, I use it and have not found any problems with it.